# Ubuntu 17.04 cannot get webcam to work on toshiba laptop L875

Tags: 17.04, webcam

I've tried everything, is it a driver problem in 17.04? Because all other past Ubuntu 16.04 and etc. it worked just fine.

Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the device is not activated yet.

1. identify your device using hwinfo.

   You may need to install it first.

   `sudo apt-get install hwinfo`
2. List the details of your devices.

   `hwinfo --usb`

   The result may shown as below:

   ```
   03: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
     [Created at usb.122]
     Unique ID: xJ63.LO5zjwIvSt9
     Parent ID: ADDn.4Nx_qoDfSd7
     SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0
     SysFS BusID: 1-1.6:1.0
     Hardware Class: unknown
     Model: "Chicony Electronics Lenovo Integrated Camera (0.3MP)"
     Hotplug: USB
     Vendor: usb 0x04f2 "Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd"
     Device: usb 0xb217 "Lenovo Integrated Camera (0.3MP)"
     Revision: "8.54"
     Driver: "uvcvideo"
     Driver Modules: "uvcvideo"
     Device File: /dev/input/event17
     Device Files: /dev/input/event17, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Chicony_Electronics_Co.__Ltd._Integrated_Camera-event-if00, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.6:1.0-event
     Device Number: char 13:81
     Speed: 480 Mbps
     Module Alias: "usb:v04F2pB217d0854dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00in00"
     Driver Info #0:
       Driver Status: uvcvideo is not actived
       Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe uvcvideo"
     Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
     Attached to: #12 (Hub)
   ```
3. activated as sugested in **Driver Ativation Cmd** section.

   `modprobe uvcvideo`

hope it works

ref: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Set_up_a_Webcam_with_Linux#Troubleshooting